# How do I examine the member configurations of an EntityTypeConfiguration<T> instance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework Code First with map classes inheriting from EntityTypeConfiguration.  I do this to encapsulate my use of the Code First fluent API for configuring entities.

I would like to be able to examine the configuration settings made in these classes, so that I can apply some of them in my integration testing. I'm using AutoFixture to create entities quickly, and ultimately I want to figure out a way to make some customizations that consume the configurations inside of my EntityTypeConfiguration classes.

But first, I need to figure out how to pull them out...

Here's a use case example:

```cs
public class Widget { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class WidgetMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Widget> {
   this.Property(w => w.Name).HasMaxLength(10);
}
```

How do I do something like this pseudo-code:

```cs
public Widget GetWidgetHonoringStringLengthConstraints(WidgetMap map) {
   var w = new Widget();
   int maxLength = map.GetProperty(p => p.Name).GetMaxLength(); //MAGIC
   string name = new Guid().SubString(0, maxLength);
   w.Name = name;
   return w;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a reply from Arthur Vickers in the [Entity Framework Codeplex Discussions](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/455031).

Essentially, he told me I'm barking up the wrong tree, because, by design, they didn't want the configuration classes to be inspected from the normal public surface - the idea being that it would pollute the API and trying to find something like the max length of a string would often tell you the story, but not the whole story (the ultimate max length restriction may have come from several conventions, including a default setting), which might not always give you the answer you are really after.

He recommended getting the metadata from the model after being built, through the [MetadataWorkspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace(v=vs.100).aspx) which can be accessed like this:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace
```

I haven't pursued implementing this yet, but I'll mark this as the answer until someone submits another answer (either an example of this before I get around to it, or another option).