# How to retrieve Entity Configuration from Fluent Api

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

Using Entity-Framework 6 I'm able to set up the configuration through Fluent Api like this:

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(d => d.Id);
        this.Ignore(d => d.UserId);
    }
}
```

<sub>Source from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753560/entity-framework-seeding-with-identity-microsoft-owin-security-user)</sub>

Using the attribute approach I'm able to know what's the property roles by reflection, but I wonder how can I retrieve these configurations, like `Key` for example, with Fluent Api approach?

There's no public property from the `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` class.

Is that possible to get the `Key` and `ForeignKey` somehow?

Comment: The fluent API is used to configure the entities/the relationships, not to get/display the constraints

Comment: @GkMoreira Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26680046/2441442

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt previously someone else did recommended to use metadataworkspace. After some research I figured it out using this approach. It's functional now, I'll elaborate an answer with that I've implemented to help anybody with same need.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt in fact It does. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a [`MetadataWorkspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) class which provides API to retrieve metadata about storage, model, CLR types and mappings for Entity Framework.

> Represents the ADO.NET metadata runtime service component that
>   provides support for retrieving metadata from various sources.

Having an instance of `DbContext`, you can find its `MetadataWorkspace` using following code:

```
var metadataWorkspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
```

Then you can get item collections which contain different types of models including object model, the conceptual model, the storage (database) model, and the mapping model between the conceptual and storage models.

The following extension methods returns [`EntityType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.metadata.edm.entitytype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for given clr type:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;

public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static EntityType GetEntityMetadata<TEntity>(this DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));

        var metadataWorkspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext)
            .ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
        var itemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadataWorkspace
            .GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));
        var entityType = metadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
            .Where(e => itemCollection.GetClrType(e) == typeof(TEntity)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (entityType == null)
            throw new Exception($"No entity mapped to CLR type '{typeof(TEntity)}'.");

        return entityType;
    }
}
```

Then you can use `EntityType` to extract more information about the model, for example you can find a list of key properties:

```
var keys = dbcontext.GetEntityMetadata<Category>().KeyProperties.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Related - This article helped me to understand and to develop the solution: https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/230583-metadataworkspace-in-entity-framework?utm_source=blog.cincura.net

Comment: Is `IObjectContextAdapter` still available in .NetCore 2.2?  I can't seem to find a reference to System.Data.Entity.

Comment: @RHarris The question is tagged with Entity Framework 6. It's not about EF core.

Comment: This didnt work for me. I did the check like this: _context.GetEntityMetadata<T>().Properties["Code"].Nullable, it returned true. I was expecting False for my case as my "Code" property is registered as IsRequired using FluentApi. I did notice that my other non-string properties that are registered as IsRequired, they do return false as expected. Not sure why it wont pick up for strings. Any insight into this would be great.