# How do you check if a property has IsRequired() on an object using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, ef-fluent-api

I have a string property it is configured as IsRequired() using FluentAPI. How do I check if this property is required? I'm iterating through all properties of my object using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to achieve this via reflection because Fluent API does not emit any CLR type data (if you have used data annotations it would be quite trivial just by looking for corresponding attributes on properties). You will need to examine the `Model` property of the context or `EntityType` of the `DbSet` to get this metadata. Something along this lines, for example:

```
// var entityType = ctx.Model.GetEntityTypes()
//    .Where(type => type.ClrType == typeof(Person))
//    .First();
// or
var entityType = ctx.Persons.EntityType;
var property = entityType.FindProperty("PrimaryAddressId");
var required = !property.IsNullable;
```

Comment: On my dbcontext, there is no Model  property nor a EntityType on the dbset.

Comment: @User123 what version of EF are you using?

Comment: Entity Framework 6

Comment: I used an extension method (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51965836/5731463) that returns EntityType, and when I did the check like this _context.GetEntityMetadata<T>().Properties["Code"].Nullable,  it returned true. I was expecting False. My property is registered as IsRequired using FluentApi

Comment: I checked another property that is also not null in the db (int, not null) and it returns false for nullable. Wondering if Nullable is returning true because the CLR type is string in which case this doesnt help at all.

Comment: @User123 I don't have EF 6 setup available, can't say, sorry.